# CST timezone add one day from november 3rd in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I tried to add one day from November 3rd with timezone like dallas, but i can't do it.

```
NSDate *intime = @"2013-11-03 05:00:00 +0000";

NSDate *nextday= [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:24*3600 sinceDate:intime];

NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *convert=[formatter stringFromDate:nextday];
NSLog(@"convert:%@",convert);
```

Nslog values:

```
intime:  2013-11-03 05:00:00 +0000
nextday: 2013-11-04 05:00:00 +0000
convert: 11/03/2013 23:00:00 // but I need this 11/04/2013.
```

Please let me know, how to do that,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to set format to something like "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss zzzzz"

Comment: thanks but it comes 11/03/2013 11:00:00 Central Standard Time

Comment: I mean that you need to use the same format as you've used for creating intime. Also you may create a new date by this way:       NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [offsetComponents setDay:1];
        NSDate *nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];

Comment: You're setting "inttime" with a NSString, not an NSDate.  It should be throwing an exception on the second line.  (I'm guessing you omitted some lines.)

Comment: "convert" is correct, BTW, taking into account timezone.

Comment: nerowolfe: thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `intime` - you have to use formatter to initialize a `NSDate` from string. So my tested example would be:

```
//  NSDate *intime = @"2013-11-03 05:00:00 +0000"; // wrong

NSString *str =@"2013-11-03 05:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *intime = [formatter dateFromString:str];

NSDate *nextday= [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:24*3600 sinceDate:intime];

NSDateFormatter *formatter2=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *convert=[formatter2 stringFromDate:nextday];
NSLog(@"%@, %@, %@", intime, nextday, convert);
```

The output is:

> > 2013-08-08 15:03:23.762 2013-11-03 05:00:00 +0000, 2013-11-04 05:00:00 +0000, **11/04/2013**

*One small comment:* by default XCode writes out these kind of problems with the code when showing issues is switched on (Preferences->General->Show live issues).
Eg. in this case XCode warns you with this issue: `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSDate *__strong' with an expression of type 'NSString *'`